# How to choose appropriate controller to handle a request in MVC?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, controller

I want to create a post so I'm using the create method of post controller. but this page has category and subcategory fields and I want to get the subcategories using AJAX.

The question is which controller is more appropriate to get the subcategories?

- AJAX controller
- Post controller
- Category controller

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one method then you should implement it in `CategoryController` because maybe other entities of your project will have relations with categories. It doesn't make sense to query route to `PostController` to get categories for select on, let's say, user category permissions editing page.

But if you need a bunch more methods it would be better to delegate a separate `CategoryApiController` for different AJAX methods and group it's routes separately too.